# Series expansion at $0$

Tags: characteristic-functions

Given: $X$, $Y$ iid random variables, $\mathbb E(X) = 0$, $\mathbb E(X^2) = 1$; $X+Y$  and $X-Y$ are independent; $\phi$ is the characteristic function of $X$ and $Y$ and $ \psi: t \rightarrow \dfrac{\phi(t)}{\phi(-t)}$.

What is, in this case, the series expansion of $\phi$ and $\psi$ at $0$?

Comment: Did you mean $X$ _and_ $Y$ are independent?  (If so, it's redundant since you already said "i.i.d.".)

Comment: Might you have meant the series expansion of $\psi$ rather than of $\phi$ at $0$?  If not, then what does $\psi$ have to do with the question?

Comment: In fact, I meant both, Phi and Psi. 
And yes, X and Y are Independent.

Comment: Then what does Y have to do with the question?

Comment: For this question: Nothing. I'd have another one, which I wanted to ask later, but I can do it also right now: Why is this property valid?: if $psi(t) = 1$ for any t in R, then X and Y are Standard Gaussian random variables.

Comment: @Did : As the question is now written, I think it's clear what $Y$ has to do with it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Indeed. JohnD: Your last comment, written after the radical revision of your question Michael alludes to, makes no sense: NOW, Y is needed, to express the crucial hypothesis that X+Y and X-Y are independent.